# Multiple Row Concatenate Macro in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet of x amount of names, with the last name being in column A, and the first name in column B. I am trying to concatenate them to get the First(B) and Last(A) name in the same Column for the entire list of names. Was wondering if someone has or could write a macro for this so it will read in one column ("lastname", "firstname") x amount of times. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? As this question stands, I doubt anyone will answer you. Well, mostly because "wondering if someone has or could write a macro for this". People on this site will not write code for you. There are people willing to help you if you face an error, a problem, etc. If you don't show any effort, neither will other people.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub NameGenerator()
    Dim N As Long, DQ As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, 3) = "(" & DQ & Cells(i, 2) & ", " & Cells(i, 1) & DQ & ")"
    Next i
End Sub
```